Inquiry Regarding Consciousness and Subjective Experience
I am writing to share a personal experience I have lived with since birth, and I am seeking an explanation or guidance regarding it through your expertise in consciousness studies. For a long time, I have felt something unconventional in my subjective experience, and I believe this condition may have a philosophical or psychological nature.
What I am experiencing relates to human consciousness and subjective experience, which I have known since birth. I have always felt that I am in a state of observing human experience through my eyes, where I observe the world around me and live it, while the body seems like a tool for carrying out this experience. The consciousness I experience seems to perceive reality, which makes me feel as though I am experiencing life as an observer.
This phenomenon raises philosophical and psychological questions related to phenomenology, especially regarding how an individual experiences their existence and reality. How does consciousness perceive itself? How does this perception differ from the way the body perceives events?
Could this feeling be the result of a kind of personal existentialism, where consciousness experiences life while the body is merely a tool subject to this experience?
I would greatly appreciate any guidance, research references, or insights you may have regarding this experience from a philosophical or psychological perspective. Is this experience considered a state of heightened consciousness? Or does it represent an existential experience indicating a separation of the person from the meanings of life and existence?

Cross-posted on skeptics.se. We ask that you don't clutter the network with duplicates. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help], paying particular attention to the [ask] section.

Sounds like depersonalization, which is a dissociative symptom. I’d look at the psychology before making any grand philosophical conclusions.

In the philosophical work of Husserl and Merleau-Ponty, phenomenology examines how consciousness experiences itself and the world as a dissociative third person POV in addition to the intentional Manas Aboutness as the first person POV. In phenomenological terms you might be experiencing a heightened awareness of what’s called the transcendental ego, a pure observing self that stands apart from physical existence. What you’re experiencing might not be unusual from the standpoint of the Eastern philosophical traditions, which view this observer state as a step toward self-realization...

I am exploring the concept of self-awareness, one of the greatest mysteries in philosophy and neuroscience. It seems that I live my consciousness as an observer of experiences through my body, but I feel a partial detachment from it, much like Descartes described when he said, "I think, therefore I am." Here, I use my body as a tool to receive experiences, but my consciousness remains somewhat detached, as if I am watching events through my senses without fully engaging in them.
.

Consider looking in to Nonduality. The experience of an observer is very common to people who meditate, and shows that their awareness is approaching non-dual. After that, fortunately, it goes away.

There isn't enough description of the state in your OP to fully understand what you are describing.  But in general, it sounds like dissociation.  Dissociation is a named psychological condition that is considered not to be healthy.  Here is a quick summary:   https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/dissociation-overview.
Alternatively, you may just be experiencing the standard "I am my thoughts not my body" experience that is the reason most people are Cartesian dualists.
In contrast to your focus on being an observer, there is a strong movement in psychology and philosophy of mind today to emphasize how much ACTING rather than observing is key to what our minds do.  This movement is called Embodied Cognition, and the SEP has a summary from a philosophic perspective:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/embodied-cognition/
As an interesting aside on embodiment, the best NASA Rover drivers all end up adopting a POV that they ARE the Rover, while they are doing the planning and driving.  https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.7208/9780226156019-008/pdf?licenseType=restricted&srsltid=AfmBOoovTvTTRo8dbT2BfgbZUWxujQDOWry4xQ17GgH7hh-w_1C6IFUa  Despite their consciousness clearly being here on earth, and "embodied" in a human body.  Most of we humans psychologically "embody" more than we than "dissociate".
However, pluralism is also a feature of most of our physiology and our models -- both A AND B can be and are true for us.  We can be our mind, not our bodies, while we think and act in an embodied fashion...

I am exploring the concept of self-awareness, one of the greatest mysteries in philosophy and neuroscience. It seems that I live my consciousness as an observer of experiences through my body, but I feel a partial detachment from it, much like Descartes described when he said, "I think, therefore I am." Here, I use my body as a tool to receive experiences, but my consciousness remains somewhat detached, as if I am watching events through my senses without fully engaging in them.

From the perspective of neuroscience, I see that my mind processes sensory information, but my conscious experience remains subjective. I feel my consciousness as the observer that gives meaning to the experiences. In existential philosophy, as seen in the ideas of Sartre and Camus, my consciousness interacts with reality as an independent entity, questioning the meaning of life and existence.

In the end, this experience makes me feel like an external observer connected to my body in one way, but detached from it in another, raising deep questions within me about the relationship between consciousness and the body.

@HameedAhmed -- I fully understand the theory that I am my mind not my body.  If all aspects of my body were to fail, as Steven Hawking's body failed, I could still engage   the questions of philosophy, science, engineering, etc that are in many cases foci of my life.  However, I am also embodied, and enjoying the process of doing things is critical to at least my psychological health.  There is a harmful psychological draw to live too much in abstractions, when what matters is this world and the people and creatures in it.  Practice engagement, caring, and affection.  You will prosper.

@HameedAhmed there is a ways to go beyond existentialism.

I experienced something like this in my youth, and it did worry me for a long time. Ultimately, I concluded that it was caused by my observing of myself.
Once you observe yourself, you cannot BE yourself. To observe something or someone necessitates a certain distance between the observed and the observer. So, when you try to observe yourself, you mentally position your observing self at a certain distance from your observed self. IOW, too much introspection may introduce a form of alienation. I guess that's what people mean by phrases like "He is too much self-aware".
If this diagnostic is correct, then the cure is in going a bit easy with introspection and self-analysis. Accept that you will never be totally transparent to yourself, that you cannot constantly second-guess yourself, that you need to BE yourself once in a while, ie you need to allow yourself to be an actor fully engaged in his/her actions, all in, without any analysis or self-criticism, at least once in a while.
In short, give yourself a break.


consciousness experiences life while the body is merely a tool subject to this experience?

'Fraid so, yeah.
Existentialism is the smart man's burden.
The secret I discovered all too late though, is, it doesn't have to be so burdensome.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, research references,

Research? The place to look for guidance is not in the bible but in the mirror.

regarding this experience from a philosophical or psychological perspective.

It would be psychological, yeah. But you did ask.

Is this experience a state of heightened consciousness?

It is if you consider consciousness to be the height of existence.
THE BRAIN IS THE MOST IMPORTANT ORGAN IN THE BODY!
...says the brain.

Or does it separate you from the meanings of life and existence?

It separates you from the meaning of life and existence.
See, you already knew that, but it didn't make any difference. Knowledge is not power.  But truth can still be beauty! As Dusty said in a Twilight Zone, "The Magic! You must pay heed to the magic!"
You're  The Enemy Within episode of Star Trek TOS.
When she wasn't passed out face down on the floor, Mom told me, "The unexamined life is not worth living." She was wrong about everything else, too. And it was probably  why she was passed out on the floor, PhD in hand.
Pay attention by all means! Stuff is interesting! But make sure you also pay attention to wonderful experience, like figure skating on the ice, spinning around and around and around! Or bouncing up and down on a trampoline, higher and higher, until you fly away.
Or sitting around the fire laughing with your friends.
Or doing the only thing we're actually supposed to do: find your other half and merge with them and become part of God, even if it's only for a few moments.
Understanding stuff is a completely different kind of wonderful. I can tell you all about that. But ultimately, all numbers add up to nothing. An intelligent animal is still an animal.
It is important to allocate attention to both modes of experience.  Because if  one decides to stomp the other (e.g., Classical Stoicism), it results in an unendurable feeling that doesn't have a name, but is expressed as either undirected grief or anger at other people.
You're a quantum field, see, oscillating  between the real and the imaginary, each mode believing the other is illusion.
It's a Yin-Yang thang.
============
Hey, I told you this was going to be psychological.
